# Android : cannot resolve android.util.Base64

Tags: java, android, base64

I spend all afternoon to find a way to read a PEM RSA Private Key into an Android application, and thanks to a lot of posts and error situations published here I've managed to convert PKCS#1 to PKCS#8 and do a lot of other things. It's working (beautifuly) fine now in a Helper Class "RsaHelper".

Problem:

Now that I know that "RsaHelper" is working inside the App, I need to move it to an external "library" (jar), but with the same source code inside the library, Android Studio reports a error "import android.util.Base64" (Cannot resolve symbol Base64).

I'm not an expert in "library"s, and actually this is my first "library" in Android Studio, so I really dont' know if I'm missing some "dependencies"? (which one?) or if the "library" itself have some kind of limitations on accessing "android...." libraries !? or if I have to rewrite my "RsaHelper" class without using "android.util.Base64" ?

I don't know if it helps, but my build.gradle (library) looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}    
sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

Can someone explain or point me what's wrong (dependencies? limitations? have to rewrite?, other?).

regards,

AS

Comment: You are using `apply plugin: 'java'`. This says that you are creating a pure Java module, and Java does not have classes in the `android.*` family of packages.

Comment: That's make sense, because the library was supposed to be a plain "jar". So I'll have to rewrite the "base64" part. Thank you!